# Preserving Formatting from HTML to textarea

Tags: javascript, html, angular, textarea

I use markdown for text editing within my project. The markdown is converted to HTML and stored in the database for rendering in the view.

Currently, when users would like to edit a post, for example, the stored text is pulled from the database and used as the initial value in the `textarea` that my markdown editor/converter makes use of.

It's easy enough to strip the tags from the text so they don't show up in the `textarea`, but I'd really like to preserve things like line breaks as well.

This seems possible, as Stackoverflow uses markdown and during editing line breaks from the text being edited are preserved in the `textarea`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The markdown is converted to HTML and stored in the database for rendering in the view.

This is your problem.

You should store the markdown and then use that in your textarea.

Comment: While this seems like a valid point, would this address the issue of line breaks?

Comment: @J.AdamConnor — Since the line breaks exist in the markdown (but the HTML will have `<p>` instead): Yes.